# How to control display in UIPickerView using selected state of button

Tags: iphone

hi i have used UIButton and also UIpickerview,when i select value(select team) ,the value is changed(india).but
when i hold the button(india) ,the value is changed to initial value(select team).if i release the button from pressing ,the value is changed(india).but i want to do when i hold , the button must show (india) ...i want to use **selected state configuration**...anyhelp?

Answer (score 0):

What is value here? UIPicker's value? or it's some other control in your view?

Check out Highlighted state for UIButton in Interface Builder... hope this helps!

Comment: i checked Highlighted state for UIButton in Interface Builder.when i pressed buttton(i did not release it),the initial value is shown

Comment: Ok, so you want to show some specific value when the button is in highlighted state, right?

Use setTitle:forState: method of UIButton and use UIControlStateHighlighted for the state.